# Create a remote git repo from local folder

Tags: git

I think there must be an easier way to do this. Right now I find myself following these steps:

**On the remote:**

```
mkdir my_repo
cd my_repo
git init --bare
```

**Then locally:**

```
mv my_repo old_my_repo
git clone ssh://myserver/my_repo
mv old_my_repo/* my_repo
rmdir old_my_repo
cd my_repo
git add .
git commit -m 'foo'
git push origin master
```

Is there some shortcut?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Unfortunately almost all steps are necessary, even though locally you can avoid to recreate the repo by cloning it.

Just init the repo and add a remote

```
cd my_repo
git init
git remote add origin ssh://myserver/my_repo
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin master
```

Note that the `-u` option will add a tracking reference, so later on you can simply type `git push` instead of `git push origin master`.

Comment: I often find myself to `git pull origin master` with the `--allow-unrelated-histories` flag.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Gabriele almost worked for me.

Before the `git push -u origin master` a `git init --bare my_repo` needs to be called in the directory that `ssh:://myserver` points to.